# Creating rectangle polygons within Multipolygons with shapely

Tags: shapely

I'm looking for wa way to create a set of poylgons (rechtangles) within multipolygons along a line and evely space them like in the drawing.

I tried to to generate points and use them as midpoints for the polygon but the problem is that by creating a evenly spaced point raster its not possible to rotate in any other orientation but 180 degrees.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f15Mu.png)

given is a mulitopolygon shapely object and the polygon defined by widght and height as well as the vertical and horizontal spacing between each polygon.
The polygons should only be placed within the multipolygon and not intersect.

extra question: Maybe there is a way to puth them along a vector so its possible to rotate the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your spacing distances and rectangle dimensions are in meters. Try the following.

```
import folium
import geopy
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPoint


def get_rectangle_points(coordinates, bearing, width, height):
    start = geopy.Point(coordinates)
    hypotenuse = np.hypot(width/1000, height/1000)
    d = geopy.distance.distance(kilometers=hypotenuse/2)

    opposite_angle = np.degrees(np.arctan(width/height))
    northeast_angle = 0 - opposite_angle
    southwest_angle = 180  - opposite_angle
    northwest_angle = opposite_angle
    southeast_angle = 180 + opposite_angle

    points = []
    for angle in [northeast_angle, northwest_angle, southwest_angle, southeast_angle]:
        point = d.destination(point=start, bearing=angle+bearing)
        coords = (point.latitude, point.longitude)
        #coords = (point.longitude, point.latitude)
        points.append(coords)

    return points

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 52.518172, 50.072651, 48.853033, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 13.407759, 14.435935, 2.349553, 4.377184]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))

latmin, lonmin, latmax, lonmax = polygon_geom.bounds

v = 100 #vertical spacing in meters
h = 500 #horizontal spacing in meters
height = 20000
width = 50000

vertical_spacing = geopy.units.degrees(arcminutes=geopy.units.km(meters=2*v+height)) #spacing in degrees
horizontal_spacing = geopy.units.degrees(arcminutes=geopy.units.km(meters=2*h+width)) #spacing in degrees
x, y = np.round(np.meshgrid(np.arange(latmin, latmax, horizontal_spacing), np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, vertical_spacing)),4)
points = MultiPoint(list(zip(x.flatten(),y.flatten())))
valid_points = []
valid_points.extend([i for i in points if polygon_geom.contains(i)])

map_coords = [polygon_geom.centroid.y, polygon_geom.centroid.x]

webmap = folium.Map(map_coords, zoom_start=6)
folium.GeoJson(polygon_geom).add_to(webmap)

for point in valid_points:
    coords = (point.y, point.x)
    rect_coords = get_rectangle_points(coords, 0, width, height) #increase bearing to rotate rectangle    
    folium.Polygon(rect_coords, color='red').add_to(webmap)

webmap.save('webmap.html')
```

[image]

Comment: I cant thank you enought. I love the sollution its exactly what i need. i will try it out myself and get back to you. thax a lot man!